# Android ListView with Button is not selectable(Clickable)

Tags: android, listview, xml-layout

I am facing a strange problem, I have added a Custom row in my ListView when I am removing the Button row is selectable, but as I add Button I am not able to click the row, please see the xml below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="77dp"
    android:layout_height="77dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:src="@drawable/company_logo" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Idds  sdsad "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"

    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:textColor="#8b8989"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:text="Tap to see detail"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Please help why this is happening.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try setting

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

to your `Button` in the xml. The `Button` gain focus over the row, that's why you can't select your row.

Answer (score 27):

As you are using your custom row.

After setting `onclickListener` for `button` in your `getView`, set its `focusability false`.

i.e  `button.setFocusable(false)`;

And also set `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` for your layout container of your row.
  You can directly set `android:focusable="false"` but this will make your button not clickable.

Comment: setting android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" on the layout container of the row was sufficient to solve this problem for me. I didn't have to do anything with the button's focusable property.

Comment: Even better solution, as it is more declarative and high-level. Very nice.