# onListItemClick() method not working

Tags: android, listview

I'm using custom layout for list item of `listView` that named `row.xml`

This is my `row.xml` file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textSize="40sp" 
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"  />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/delete_btn"
           style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_gravity="right"
           android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
           android:gravity="right|center"
           android:text="delete" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

With the above layout, `onListItemClick()` method not working,but when i remove the `Button` element from layout, it's working correctly.

Please let me to know what's the problem

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16119643/android-listview-with-button-is-not-selectableclickable. check this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "Raghunandan" 's help, i'm add

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

to `Button` ,and my problem solved

The `Button` gain focus over the row, that's why we can't select the row